# C Array manipulation questions

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

So i have a few questions about reading into arrays(very new to c)
I have this code so far

```
int xZac[stCrt];
int xKonc[stCrt];
int yZac[stCrt];
int yKonc[stCrt];
for (int i=0; i < stCrt; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &xZac[i]); 
    scanf("%d", &yZac[i]);
    scanf("%d", &xKonc[i]);
    scanf("%d", &yKonc[i]);
    int c = xKonc[i]-xZac[i];
    printf("%d", c);
    //the values here shoud be  xKonc[0]=49, xZac[0] = 0, it outprints 490
   // but i need the actual difference between those in other inputs
   //it also only returns it once even tho on the first input there should     be 2 such values
  //on another instance(maybe im reading them wrong?) xKonc[0]=29 and xZac[0]=0 but the output is 2907220
}
```

Is this the proper way of reading into an array?
How do i then get the value of this, i need to use it in for statement later on but i cant seem to get it right. How would i say get the number of xKonc[i]-xZac[i]. it seems to return pointers or something when i try it. So what id like to know is how to subtract actual integers from arrays, and if im reading the data right or is the problem there

Comment: You can print `xKonc[i]` and `xZac[i]` to be sure that there no errors in reading the data from the file.

Comment: It reads 4910, when it should read 49, any solutions on that?

Comment: your code looks right so there is something odd going on, put printf("%d %d" xConc[i], xZac[i])

Comment: How about a sample of your input, especially if you're reading from a file? Also, try using `printf("%d\n", c);` to display items on separate lines. You might be getting the right input, but your output may be running together.

Comment: Thanks joe, i completely missed that, so we got that part fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with this. Can you include your input file? I would venture to bet you are printing a 49 and a 0, without a newline character, causing you to think you are printing 490

Comment: That was the issue, i completely missed that, thanks